# At which instance does reading an InputStream.read() return a positive integer and when does it return -1?

Tags: java, stream, network-programming

I have a few questions about the way `InputStream.read()` works. I'm trying to listen on `InputStream` and whenever bytes are available, I need them to be copied to a byte array and then the byte array is handed off to another method for further processing and then return to listening to the InputStream for next set of bytes. Here's how far I've gotten:

```
while(true){
    while((i = inputstream.read(recvBuffer, 0, recvBuffer.length)) != -1){
    doSomething(recvBuffer);
    }
}
```

I read that `read(byte[] b, int off, int len)` method returns an `int` that is supposed to represent the number of bytes read from the stream. Doesn't that mean whenever bytes are available, it sets the value of `i` to the respective number of bytes? Once it reads `x` number of bytes and reaches the end of the stream, wouldn't it return a positive integer representing the number of bytes, instead of `-1`? Then, when would the check against `-1` happen for `i`? I know I'm interpreting this wrong but I can't say how. Any help understanding this would be appreciated

Also, I know the max amount of bytes that a sender can push onto a stream. In this case, is it sufficient to specify the size of `recvBuffer` as the max amount of bytes or is it prudent to allocate a bit more than that?

Comment: No. At the end of the stream it returns `-1` (to indicate the end of the stream).

Comment: you should pass the number of bytes that were read to your doSomething method to make it easy on yourself when parsing the byte array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
doSomething(recvBuffer);
```

That should be

```
doSomething(recvBuffer, i);
```

The method needs to know how many bytes were actually received.

> I read that read(byte[] b, int off, int len) method returns an int that is supposed to represent the number of bytes read from the stream.

Correct.

> Doesn't that mean whenever bytes are available, it sets the value of
>   i to the respective number of bytes?

Yes.

> Once it reads x number of bytes
>   and reaches the end of the stream, wouldn't it return a positive
>   integer representing the number of bytes, instead of -1?

No, it transfers the bytes and returns the count, then the next time there are no bytes, only end of stream, so it returns -1.

> Then, when would the check against -1 happen for i? I know I'm interpreting this
>   wrong but I can't say how.

See above.

> Also, I know the max amount of bytes that a sender can push onto a stream. In this case, is it sufficient to specify the size of recvBuffer as the max amount of bytes or is it prudent to allocate a bit more than that?

Most people use 4096 or 8192 bytes. There's not a lot of point in specifying a buffer larger than the path MTU in truth, which is normally < 1500, unless you are slow at reading so that the kernel socket receive buffer fills up.